# Change the border color of the checkbox and radio button

Tags: html, css

How to change the border color of the checkbox and radio button (circle and rectangle color) using CSS?

I tried lot but not getting a correct one.

Please advice me?

Comment: In what browser are you looking? Some browser don't allow you to change the style of those elements.

Comment: check this: https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr#newwindow=1&sclient=psy-ab&q=css%20custom%20checkbox%20and%20radio%20button&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.50165853,d.bmk&fp=55ad5f80dce46606&biw=1215&bih=938&pf=p&pdl=300

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It simply is not possible. However, there is a workaround where the actual checkbox is made invisible and the styled label is used as an overlay. Looks good and works fine.

More about it here: http://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the checkbox with a div and then put a border around it or create a `table` and put border around the `td`

```
div{
   border: 1px solid red
}
```

or

```
td{
   border: 1px solid red
}


<div>
   <input type="checkbox"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a custom radio button.
You can use js to show or hide a image. Image will be looks like as designed check box and original checkbox should be hide.
Change the value of checkbox on image click.