# How can I change the color of a radio button border in Chrome & Firefox using only CSS?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, radio-button, border

How can I change the border-color of a radio button in Chrome & Firefox using only CSS? I've added the following to my css file and it doesn't change the appearance from the browser default settings.

```
input[type="radio"] {
    border: 1px solid $ltbrown;
  }
```

I've also tried "outline" instead of border, but that creates a square border around the default circular border.

Comment: I don't think that's possible without the use of images. Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460501/how-to-change-checkboxs-border-style-in-css

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if its possible to do this. But you can try this:
[http://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack](http://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/)

The question sounds kind of same as:
[Change the border color of the checkbox and radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17993954/change-the-border-color-of-the-checkbox-and-radio-button)

Answer (score 0):

This works in chrome, but not firefox (actually trying to figure out how to fix it in firefox right now when I stumbled on this).  Hopefully this helps

For the color of the center part of the checked radio:

`input[type="radio"]:checked:after {
    background-color: #6bc298;
}`

for the border color:

`box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #6bc298;`

Answer (score 0):

If you set the CSS property `appearance:none` then you can fully style any field, including checkboxes and radio buttons.